# $_SESSION Se pierde al pasar de mi login a index

Tags: php, html

quisiera hacer una consulta, estoy intentando realizar un login, estoy seguro de que se está efectuando bien porque se está validando el usuario y la contraseña, el problema es de que cuando realizamos la redirección a "index.php" antes de eso creo $_SESSION con valores como "Nombre, Apellido, etc" pero cuando los intento acceder nuevamente estos aparecen vacíos o que no existen.

Código PHP **AUTENTICAR.PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
include( 'acceso_db.php' );
global $wrongPwdErr, $accountNotExistErr, $emailPwdErr, $verificationRequiredErr, $email_empty_err, $pass_empty_err;
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'iniciar' ] ) ) {
  $usuario_login = $_POST[ 'username' ];
  $password_login = $_POST[ 'pwd' ];

  $pwd_cryp = mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $password_login );

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_email = '{$usuario_login}'";
  $query = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );
  $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows( $query );
  if ( !$query ) {
    die( "Sql Query Failed" . mysqli_error( $conn ) );
  }
  if ( $rowCount <= 0 ) {
    $accountNotExistErr = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
            El usuario ingresado no existe.
            </div>';
  } else {
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
      $usuario_id = $row[ 'usuario_id' ];
      $usuario_nombre = $row[ 'usuario_nombre' ];
      $usuario_apellido = $row[ 'usuario_apellido' ];
      $usuario_email = $row[ 'usuario_email' ];
      $usuario_clave = $row[ 'usuario_clave' ];
      $is_active = $row[ 'is_active' ];
      session_regenerate_id();
      $_SESSION[ 'loggedin' ] = TRUE;
      $_SESSION[ 'usuario_id' ] = $usuario_id;
        
      $_SESSION[ 'usuario_nombre' ] = $usuario_nombre;
        
      $_SESSION[ 'apellido' ] = $usuario_apellido;
        
      $_SESSION[ 'emailDash' ] = $usuario_email;
        
      $_SESSION[ 'user_Active' ] = $is_active;
    }

    $password = password_verify( $password_login, $usuario_clave );

    if ( $is_active == '1' ) {
      if ( $usuario_login == $usuario_email && $password_login == $usuario_clave ) {

        echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location = 'index2.php';</script>";
        //echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$_SESSION[loggedin]');</script>";
      } else {
        $emailPwdErr = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.
                </div>';
      }
    } else {
      $verificationRequiredErr = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                            Se requiere la verificación de la cuenta para iniciar sesión.
                        </div>';
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Codigo Simple INICIO

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( isset( $_SESSION[ 'usuario_nombre' ] ) ) {
  ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Sitio Ejemplo Datos</title>
</head>

<body>
<span class="name"><strong class="font-weight-semibold"><?php echo "{$_SESSION['usuario_nombre']}"; ?>1</strong></span>
    
<a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="cerrar_sesion.php"><i class="bx bx-log-out"></i> Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
  echo "<script language='javascript'>";
  echo "window.location.href = 'login.php'";
  echo "</script>";
}
?>
```

Agradeceria que pudieran ayudarme, pues llevo mucho rato ya intentando solventarlo.

Comment: ¿Has depurado tu código? Sólo guardas datos en la variable de sesión en ciertos casos... verifica que el código entra en esos bloques. Aparte de eso, ¿por qué asignas datos dentro de un bucle? Debes saber que en ese caso la variable de sesión se quedará con los valores de la última fila del bucle. En fin, creo que debes clarificar un poco tu código y también depurarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano puedes ayudarme a depurarlo de la mejor manera, o indicarme adonde esta mi problema porfavor, muy probablemente dar tanta vuelta en el mismo problema me ha nublado un poco la logica, saludos.

Comment: En 1er lugar dinos, por dónde está entrando el código ahora mismo, así tendremos al menos un punto de partida. En cuando a depurar, con que pongas un `var_dump` en cada parte podrás ir viendo lo que funciona o no funciona. Y cuando tengas detectado el problema podrás refinar más cosas, como el hecho de llenar la variable de sesión... ¿Esperas una sola fila o varias filas de resultados en la consulta SQL? Si son varias filas, la forma en que llenas la variable no es correcta, si es una fila, el `while` no es necesario... Son muchas cosas y hay que ir por partes. Empieza depurando con var_dump.

Comment: Para ayudarte en la depuración, pon temporalmente estas tres líneas al inicio de tu script PHP: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Luego copia y pega los mensajes de error que verás en pantalla en la pregunta. Convendría que más adelante aprendas a leer el log de errores, el cual te ayudará a encontrar con facilidad los problemas en el código, ahorrando horas en el desarrollo.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano, comentar que he colocado las líneas que escribes con anterioridad y he logrado obtener el siguiente error "Notice: Undefined index: usuario_nombre in /var/www/html/newAdminRelease/index2.php on line 16"

Comment: En la pregunta, ¿qué bloque de código pertenece al arhivo `index2.php` y cuál es la línea 16?

Comment: Corresponde a esta: <span class="name"><strong class="font-weight-semibold"><?php echo "{$_SESSION['usuario_nombre']}"; ?>1</strong></span>

Comment: No debería dar ese error, puesto que tienes un `isset`  al principio que verifica precisamente esa clave de la variable de sesión. Aunque tienes tal mezcla de bloques PHP/HTML y cosas puestas en el sitio equivocado, que puede que haya cosas erróneas ahí. Sugiero que pongas un `var_dump($_SESSION);` al inicio del todo, antes del primer `if` y nos digas lo que mostraria ese `var_dump`.

Comment: Acabo de colocar el var_dump($_SESSION); y efectivamente me devuelve el valor NULL, por lo tanto la variable $_SESSION no esta viajando. @A.Cedano

Comment: Tu código necesita muchas mejoras, y sobre todo **coherencia**. En la primera parte, en vez de esto: `die( "Sql Query Failed" . mysqli_error( $conn ) );` mete algo en la variable de sesión, por ejemplo: `$_SESSION['error']=mysqli_error( $conn );` Si aún así no ves nada, pon también en ese archivo las tres líneas que te sugerí más arriba, a fin de ver qué errores están ocurriendo en autenticar.

Comment: Es más de lo mismo, siempre devuelve el valor NULL, haciendo los cambios que solicitas en el código @A.Cedano

Comment: Pienso que en realidad debería de reformular la manera en la cual estoy intentando loguear.

Comment: ¿Colocaste esto en autenticar? `ini_set('display_errors', '1');  ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');  error_reporting(E_ALL);` ¿Qué ves en pantalla?

Comment: Tú tienes un lío de código en muchas partes. Por ejemplo, si decides trabajar con variables de sesión, mete todo en la variable de sesión y luego verifica. Tienes una mezcla de cosas sin sentido: variable de sesión sólo para cuando hay éxito, `die` cuando hay errores, bloques con contenido HTML en autenticar, etc. **Mete absolutamente TODO** en la variable de sesión y luego verifica dicha variable. En el segundo bloque de código tienes otro lío, metiendo cosas en el `head` del HTML, y el `else` totalmente fuera del bloque completo html... deberías replantear casi todo en tu código.